# I want to know if there is any way I can store a predicate dynamically in prolog and then call it

Tags: prolog, predicate, dynamically-generated

Basically not writing it in source code.
For eg

```
:- store_in_db(mypred(A,B):- write(A),write(B)).
```

This will be my first call, the second will be

```
--> mypred('Hi ','there')
```

and it should print

```
- Hi there.
```

Answer (score 3):

Check out

```
asserta
assertz
retract
retractall
```

Comment: these functions can store a predicate, but they can't be used to execute that predicate.

Comment: Yes. These predicates take care of what you called the "first call" in the question. The "second call" looks like any other Prolog call, exactly as you wrote it in your question.

Comment: @RamChoudhary you would do well to actually try it before dismissing it.

Comment: Don't use these though except for facts. Self-modifying code is nasty and confusing, although powerful. Some powers are not meant for mere mortals, even if manifested in bog-standard Turing machines.

Comment: @WillNess, you are right, the actual problem is with swish prolog (the online complier), when I tried it with offline version (swi prolog), these predicates were working well, whereas swish prolog gives a sandbox restriction error.